# Intersection of rectangles based on the distance of their corner points as a vector

Tags: geometry

If I have two rectangles and represent them as a vector with their four corner points been concatenated into such vector (those rectangles are not rotated).

Can I use the distance between those two vectors to determine if both rectangles will intersect ?

My exact problem is that, I am using a database that can store bounding boxes as vectors. However, I can't do arbitrary computations with that database. The only thing I can do is to compute the L1 or L2 distance.
How could I check if two bounding boxes will intersect solely based on a distance metric. Note that even tough I am talking about bounding boxes, I can add arbitrary additional information into those vectors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The general way to describe a (not rotated) rectangle, is by the left-top, right-bottom points. You might decide to describe a rectangle using vectors (you might describe the left-top -> right-bottom as a vector), but you will always need a second vector to describe your starting point (mostly the left-top point). So, describing a rectangle as one single vector seems impossible to me.

Comment: Hi @Dominique, thanks for your reply. My problem is not exactly mathematical, I am more search for a mathematical solution to an engineering problem. I have added the necessary details in the original post.

Comment: Some property you may use - the dot product of at least one of the vectors needs to be between two other dot products.